# PHP Fatal error on both scripts

Tags: php

```
<?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="";      // Mysql username 
    $password="";      // Mysql password 
    $db_name="";       // Database name 
    $tbl_name="";      // Table name

    // Connect to server and select database.
    $link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");

    // Retrieve data from database
    // The 'LIMIT 10' part will only read 10 scores.
    // Feel free to change this value
    $sql="SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Start looping rows in mysql database.
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $rows['name'] . "|" . $rows['score'] . "|";
    }

    // close MySQL connection 
    mysql_close();

?>
```

Hi this is the 1st piece of code that has some kind of problem but im not very new to php and databases please help and the second piece also has a problem :(

```
<?php

    $db = "";//Your database name
    $dbu = "";//Your database username
    $dbp = "";//Your database users' password
    $host = "localhost";//MySQL server - usually localhost

    $dblink = mysqli_connect($host,$dbu,$dbp,$db);

    if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['score'])){
         // Lightly sanitize the GET's to prevent SQL injections and possible XSS attacks
         $name = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']));
         $score = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['score']));

         $sql = mysqli_query($dblink, "INSERT INTO `$db`.`scores` (`id`,`name`,`score`) VALUES ('','$name','$score');");
         if($sql){
             //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
             echo 'Your score was saved. Congrats!';
         }
         else {
             //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
             echo 'There was a problem saving your score. Please try again later.';  
         }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Your name or score wasnt passed in the request. Make sure you add ?name=NAME_HERE&score=1337 to the tags.';
    }
    //Close off the MySQL connection to save resources.
    mysqli_close($dblink);

?>
```

If needed the urls are here: [script1](https://bedfordgames.com/getscores.php),[script2](https://bedfordgames.com/savescores.php) Script 2 (savescores )works to some extent but when submitting the score it fails and script 1 (getscores) just comes back with an error check on the urls below and if anyone can please help me fix these i will be extremely greatful!

Comment: `mysql_*` functions have been removed from PHP for being *very* bad. Learn PDO instead.

Comment: you're using a mixture of mysqli and deprecated mysql. Use either mysqli or PDO and make use of prepared statements.

Comment: _"has some kind of problem"_ is a _very_ poor error description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_connect` , `mysql_select_db` , `mysql_query` `and mysql_fetch_assoc` are deprecated and  removed in `PHP 7.0.0`.

you can use ‍‍`MySQLi extension` or `PDO (PHP Data Objects)` to connect to the database.

Read [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)  for more